# What are the steps to setup SSL to work with WCF on Azure?

Tags: wcf, ssl, azure

Please post the steps you have taken to setup SSL to work with WCF on Azure.

I have my [valid certificate uploaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203056.aspx) successfully ([using cspack](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazure/thread/53b54dbc-0408-47c3-9479-9155aa1693cc/)) and working with the rest of the site, but after adding it, my previously working WCF service stopped working.  (All I get is a 404 error back to Silverlight, which is not very helpful.  Up votes to whomever comes up with some better logging I could be doing too to help diagnose the problem too!)

I've tried many variations on this configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
     <!--start added for SSL--> 
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SecureBasicHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"  />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
     <!--end added for SSL--> 
    <behaviors>
      <!--start added for SSL--> 
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DisableServiceCertificateValidation">
          <clientCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="None"
                              revocationMode="NoCheck" />
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <!--start added for SSL--> 
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Silverheat.Cloud_WebRole.API.DataServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <!-- certificate checking removed --> 
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Silverheat.Cloud_WebRole.API.DataServiceBehavior"
          name="Silverheat.Cloud_WebRole.API.DataService">
        <!--<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Silverheat.Cloud_WebRole.API.DataService" />-->
        <endpoint bindingConfiguration="SecureBasicHttpBinding"
                  behaviorConfiguration="DisableServiceCertificateValidation"
                  address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  contract="Silverheat.Cloud_WebRole.API.DataService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Unfortunately, debugging this and getting more info is really hard because I cannot step through and debug with any configuration remotely like I'd use on the live server because the [bindings tag has problems](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazure/thread/d69b7c6f-5648-417a-a379-23b0f012c4aa/) on debug (but not live).

Thanks for your help and interest!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wow!  Its alive!  Its working!!

Still doesn't work in debug ([security exception](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazure/thread/d69b7c6f-5648-417a-a379-23b0f012c4aa/)), but I'll live with that until the next release.

Here's the configuration that worked:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SecureBasicHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"  />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Silverheat.Cloud_WebRole.API.DataServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Silverheat.Cloud_WebRole.API.DataServiceBehavior"
          name="Silverheat.Cloud_WebRole.API.DataService">
        <endpoint bindingConfiguration="SecureBasicHttpBinding"
          address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          contract="Silverheat.Cloud_WebRole.API.DataService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

(I think it was "mexHttpsBinding" that made it finally work, although I don't entirely understand why it needs meta data after its already configured, back to the books I guess)

I'd still like to know how to enable some kind of logging for WCF, but I'll poke around this great site a bit more and I'm sure I'll find an answer.